# why use transposed matrix in affine2d

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, transform

According to 
http://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affine2d-class.html

Matlab expects a transposed affine transform matrix, and it applies the transform by v*T with v as a row vector instead of the standard T*v where v is a column vector.

They say a valid matrix is of the form [a b 0; c d 0; e f 1] a transpose of the common form in the literature - and what you expect when they multiply v*T instead of T*v.

Because of this, their example does a clock-wise rotation instead of a counter-clock-wise (even though they say it should do a counter-clock-wise):

```
%Define 10-Degree Rotation in the Counter-Clockwise Direction
%Create an affine2d object that defines the transformation.
theta = 10;
tform = affine2d([cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0; sind(theta) cosd(theta) 0; 0 0 1])
%Apply forward geometric transformation to an input (U,V) point (5,10).
[X,Y] = transformPointsForward(tform,5,10)
X = 6.6605
Y = 8.9798
```

They use the literature matrix for ccw rotation, but multiply in the opposite order, so they get a cw rotation... if they would transpose the matrix, it would indeed do a ccw rotation (maybe they forgot to do that in the example).

I've tested the speed of multiplying the matrix by vector from the left vs multiplying the vector by matrix - and the difference is negligible.

I guess it was a bug and they kept it for backwards compatibility? 
Anyone has any insight on this?

Comment: I'm assuming then the `v` is a vector like `[x, y]`? So maybe they just find it more intuitive to multiply a matrix of coordinates by the transform in one shot so the `v` becomes `[x1, y1; x2, y2;, x3, y3; ... xn, yn]`.  Because now you can `get v_prime = v*T` to apply the transform to all the points in one go. No idea about the transposing back at the end though, that could be because you are using a function (`transformPointsForward`) instead of just using matrix multiplication (`*`)

Comment: I was wondering too when I noticed it. I think the multiplication order vT is rather uncommon.

Comment: PDFs also seem to use this form of the transformation matrix. Presumably for the same reason, whatever that is.