# Matlab image transformation (affine2d, projective2d) ordering

Tags: matlab, image-processing

In MWE code below (taken from [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/matrix-representation-of-geometric-transformations.html)), a transformation of `T` followed by `R` is given by `T*R` instead of `R*T` as in most computer graphics or vision textbooks.

```matlab
    cb = checkerboard(4,2);
    cb_ref = imref2d(size(cb));
    background = zeros(150);
    imshowpair(cb,cb_ref,background,imref2d(size(background)))

    T = [1 0 0;0 1 0;100 0 1];
    tform_t = affine2d(T);
    R = [cosd(30) sind(30) 0;-sind(30) cosd(30) 0;0 0 1];
    tform_r = affine2d(R);

    TR = T*R; % This line
    tform_tr = affine2d(TR);
    [out,out_ref] = imwarp(cb,cb_ref,tform_tr);
    imshowpair(out,out_ref,background,imref2d(size(background)))
```

If we wanted to transform an image `x` to `x'` first by `T` then by `R`, shouldn't we do `x'=R(T(x))=R*T*x`?

From the code, tt appears to me that we are doing `x'=T*R*x` instead. This does not make sense, as the output is really doing `x'=R*T*x`. This behavior is not explained in the documentation.

Before transformation:

[image: before]

After transformation:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Matlab uses a different convention. Instead of calculating `x'=T*x`, they do `transpose(x')=transpose(T*x)` which equals `transpose(x)*transpose(T)`. As the transformation matrix is now RIGHT-MULTIPLIED, the ordering also changes. The first transformation is now on the left. (The input argument to the function is already `transpose(T)`, not `T`).

Besides `affine2d` and `projective2d`, their projection matrix created by `cameraMatrix` is also transposed -- It is of shape `4x3` instead of the traditional `3x4`.

I am not sure why they do this, some discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059835/why-use-transposed-matrix-in-affine2d). I really hope that they can better explain/point that out in the documentation for `imwarp`, `projective2d` and the like. It took me hours to figure this out.